# How to improve FFT2 in matlab,

Tags: matlab, optimization, fft

I have the following code which produces convolution of two matrices. The problem that i have is that the convolution is pretty memory consuming. Any ideas on how to make this faster?

1. How can i remove the temp variable?
2. Is there a faster way of doing fft?
3. Is there a Matlab friendlier version of this? shall i pre allocate somewhere?

   ```
   function res = fftconv(data,query)

       N = size(data,1);
       R = size(query,1);
       C = size(query,2);
       query(end+1:N,end+1:N)=0;

       temp = ifft2(fft2(data).*fft2(query));
       res = temp(R:end,C:end);

   end
   ```

Comment: You can accelerate it in GPUs..... I do not think there is a clear easy way of solving that.

Comment: fft is the fastest  algorithm for Fourier transform , it reduces your calculations from N*N to 2*N + 1 so I dont think there is anyway you can further make fft faster

Comment: You may consider optimizing the fft using [`fftw`. (read carefully beforehand.)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fftw.html) But I am afraid it does not make a big difference any way. By the way, `fft2(query, N, N)` does the padding and looks neater, although it does not change the speed.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach might accidentally compute FFTs over “bad” lengths, i.e., numbers with large prime factors.

Also, your approach does circular convolution: it won’t match the output of Matlab’s built-in `conv2` without zero-padding. (Recall that circular convolution using FFT is equivalent to time-domain linear convolution when you zeropad both inputs to `nx + ny - 1`.)

Here’s a simple function you can use, which returns the same values as `conv2`:

```
function z = conv2fft(x, y, nfft)
nx = size(x);
ny = size(y);
nz = nx + ny - 1;

if ~exist('nfft', 'var') || isempty(nfft)
  nfft = 2 .^ nextpow2(nz);
else
  assert(all(nfft >= nz), 'nfft >= nx + ny - 1 for linear convolution');
end

zfull = ifft2(fft2(x, nfft(1), nfft(2)) .* fft2(y, nfft(1), nfft(2)));

z = zfull(1 : nz(1), 1 : nz(2));
```

Check it out, it works:

```
>> x = randn(10, 11);
>> y = randn(4, 3);
>> z1 = conv2(x, y);
>> z2 = conv2fft(x, y);
>> max(abs(z2(:) - z1(:)))
ans =
   2.2204e-15
```

The error between the two is very tiny, even for rectangular inputs. You’ll need to benchmark it on your data to confirm that it’s faster.

An important caveat about speed: this function uses a default `nfft` of a power-of-2 if none is provided. Sometimes this isn’t the best. E.g., if `nx + ny - 1` is `[1025, 1025]` (i.e., the output of `conv2` is 1025 by 1025), the default will result in 2048 by 2048 intermediate arrays, which might be slower than 1025 by 1025! This is because FFTW internally has to allocate four times as much memory, and take 4x longer FFTs. *If* you know this is the case, you can give `conv2fft` a better `nfft`, e.g., `[1080, 1080]` (unique factors of 1080 are 2, 3, and 5). Julia has a nice function called [`nextprod`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/math/#Base.nextprod) that lets you find the next integer that has certain factors. Here’s a [free Matlab version of `nextprod`](https://gist.github.com/fasiha/190203eac467d8b7f9ab2c83c3b3011e), which you can use like `nextprod([2 3 5], 1025)`. This returns 1080.

In summary:

- you might get a little bit of a speedup by using “nice” FFT lengths as above.
- As one commenter suggested, you can also look at GPU-based FFTs, which can evaluate the FFT faster but you have to factor in the time needed to copy the input and output to/from the GPU.
- As another commeter suggested, you can also ask FFTW to produce a carefully-tuned plan for the exact sizes that you need—this might be a few percent faster than whatever default plan Matlab uses.
- Finally, people have also written faster FFT implementations, e.g., [FFTS](https://github.com/anthonix/ffts) but the code there is not ready for general consumption.

Comment: Thank you @ahmed I have ran the code and its only faster in smaller sets of data and my original code outperforms it in bigger data sets. I also randomly generated the data and timed it. The precision here was not an issue as they produce rather same result. (zero padding in my case happens outside the function)